# Custom Keybinds that don't interfere with other programs

Tags: keyboard, key-binding, logitech-keyboard

I have a logitech G710+ keyboard, and it has several programmable G keys on the side:

[image]

My main issue is, I'd like to create some keybinds that I can use in other programs, that normally don't interfere with other programs. For example: <kbd>F3</kbd> is set as default to the <kbd>G3</kbd> key, but if I hit that when chrome is open, it will attempt to do a search. Are there additional keys that (Maybe aren't on a normal keyboard) that I can bind to these G keys that would be ideal for keybinding with other programs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great post [here](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=40286&p=183796), which explains how you can add F13-F24 keys to your logitech commands, which you can then use as keybinds for various programs. (These keys should not interfere with most, if not all programs).

From the post:

> Open a profile in LGS, position the mouse cursor over the + by "Commands" on the left and hit F1.
>   It Sends F13, and then waits for you to click OK. 
>   It remembers where you clicked OK, then adds the other 11 bindings automatically

```
#NoEnv
#Singleinstance, Force
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
SetKeyDelay, 50, 50

OKLocated := 0

F1::
    MouseGetPos, x1, y1
    Loop 12 {
        MouseMove, x1, y1
        Click
        num := A_Index + 12
        Sleep 250
        Send % "{F" num "}"
        if (OKLocated){
            MouseClick, Left, x2, y2
        } else {
            ; Wait for user to click OK
            KeyWait, LButton, D
            KeyWait, LButton
            ; Record coords
            MouseGetPos, x2, y2
            OKLocated := 1
        }
    }
    return
```

Additionally, there is a YouTube video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YTG_3kWXqRM) that will walk you through the entire process.